# Python: Extract lists inside a list based on a condition

Tags: python, list, slice

Hi I have a list of lists, e.g.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 6], [4, 2, 5], [7, 3, 8]]
```

Based on the second element of the sublists, I would like to get:

```
b = [ [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5]],  [[5, 3, 6], [7, 3, 8]] ]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Would it be okay to do this hackily, or does it need to be programatic?

Comment: `Based on the second element of the sublists` what do you mean? Should it be sortered/filtered?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary to categorize your sublists based on second element:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i,j,k in a :
...     d.setdefault(j,[]).append([i,j,k])
... 
>>> d
{2: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5]], 3: [[5, 3, 6], [7, 3, 8]]}
>>> d.values()
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5]], [[5, 3, 6], [7, 3, 8]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort a list on the value of the second element of the sublists:

```
sorted(a, lambda a, b: a[1] - b[1])
```

Comment: a = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 6], [4, 2, 5],[5,3,2], [7, 3, 8]] ; sorted (a,lambda x , y :x[1]-y[1]) ;  O/P : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 5], [5, 3, 6], [5, 3, 2], [7, 3, 8]]
; Just saying it results in an answer ordered differently. But its a quick way and god knows what is required here ## I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Read the @HaggarTheHorrible desired output and compare to your output. You return a flat list, which is not desired

Comment: Ah, I missed the grouping. Thank you, Nhor :)